# unable to delete faulty xorg.conf

Tags: 11.10, monitor, xrandr

I upgraded to 11.10. Unfortunately, this upgrade overwrote a previous configuration file for my monitor, resulting in the "out of range" error on the monitor. (It is an old lcd screen and I need 800x600_60.0hz.) I plugged in an old CRT monitor to work on it. Not having a backup of the configuration file, I researched again how to do it. Involved xrandr and creating a new configuration. I tested this and it worked, so I wrote these settings to a xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ and rebooted. Boot started, then the screen went blank, no sync. I don't know if the boot continued or got stuck, as the screen is blank.

So, figuring it is a faulty xorg.conf, I rebooted to recovery mode and tried to delete or edit the file. I cannot edit it - file system is read only. I cannot delete it - file system is read only. I cannot change the permissions with chmod - file system is read only. I can't do anything with it!

So, I booted with a liveCD, and also cannot edit or delete it as I am not the owner. From LiveCD I then thought I'd copy the files off that I want and reinstall. But I cannot read all the folders on the desktop - not being the owner of them all (strange).

What now?! How can I:
- delete xorg.conf
- make filesystem writeable in order to delete or edit xorg.conf
- once that problem is solved, I am back at square one and need to get the right configuration for the monitor - where do I do that.

I'm not a complete novice at linux, but not overly familiar...

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: "readonly filesystem"? Sounds like your partition / disk is broken.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm assuming you are trying to edit or delete as root or using sudo.  Your general user account won't be able to touch those files normally.

If a filesystem is being mounted readonly, that usually means there is some problem with it.  You can try remounting it as read/write to see what errors (if any) appear:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1
```

/dev/sda1 is the first partition on the first hard drive - you would need to change that if your /etc lives on a different partition or hard drive.

If that gives you errors, add them to your question to help with troubleshooting.  If there are no errors, you should be able to edit the files.